# SwiftUI .autocorrectionDisabled() behavior not updating with @State BOOL

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, ipad

Using 'true' or 'false' works as expected:

```
TextEditor(text: $input)
    .autocorrectionDisabled(true)
```

But when replacing with a State variable, only the initial value is used. When the state value changes to 'false', the behavior of autocorrect doesn't change.

```
@State var shouldDisable = true  

TextEditor(text: $input)  
    .autocorrectionDisabled(shouldDisable)  
    .onReceive(aTimer) { _ in  
        if otherConditionMet {  
            withAnimation {  
                shouldDisable = false  
            }  
        print(shouldDisable)  
        }  
    }
```

The timer is firing every second to evaluate if otherConditionMet. Here's the output of the simple print statement confirming shouldDisable updates when the other condition is met:

```
`shouldDisable: true`
`shouldDisable: true`
`shouldDisable: true`
`shouldDisable: true`
`shouldDisable: true
`shouldDisable: false`
`shouldDisable: false`
`shouldDisable: false`
```

I've validated by initialing `shouldDisable` to `true` and again initializing to `false` and updating `shouldDisable = true` in the if statement. In both conditions, only the initial value is used, despite how the variable changes.

I've tried removing the `withAnimation`, as well as the order of the `.autocorrectionDisabled` modifier in the stack; neither had any effect.

I'm testing on a physical device with iOS 15 as this is my oldest supported target.

Thanks for any input!

---

**Update:** I just validated this behavior with the following bare-bones code. The bool toggles to false, but the TextEditor does not re-enable autocorrection:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var input = ""
    @State var autocorrectionDisabled = true

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TextEditor(text: $input)
                .autocorrectionDisabled(autocorrectionDisabled)
                .font(.headline)
         
            Button("Toggle Autocorrection") {
                autocorrectionDisabled.toggle()
                print("autocorrectionDisabled: \(autocorrectionDisabled)")
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I'd be interested to hear others' results and ideas about how to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

You can "reset" the `TextField` if you set the `Bool` as the `id`

```
TextEditor(text: $input)
    .autocorrectionDisabled(autocorrectionDisabled)
    .font(.headline)
    .id(autocorrectionDisabled)
```

This makes the `TextField` lose focus, so you would have to compensate for that using `FocusState` or leave it as is and expect to user to trigger focus.

Comment: Thank you for providing a workaround.The loss of focus on the TextEditor really does impact the usability. We are already using FocusState so it was quick to test out; but having the keyboard lower and then raise in quick succession makes the experience even less enjoyable. We'll keep searching for a solution.